# How can I call provider method from global service method in ionic 2, angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to insert data from an API call to the database. The API call is done from the global services. When I tried to do it within the constructor method it is working. But if I try it from an other outside method from service I am getting an error “ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMetadataKey' of undefined(…)”.

```
import { Database } from './../providers/database/database';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class mAppService{
showValue: string;
public database;
userLoggedIn: boolean = false;
constructor(database: Database) {
//If i call the database method from here its working**
}
getConnect(ipaddress,portnumber){
    try {
    var t = ipaddress;
    var p = portnumber;
    client = new linear.client({transports: [
                                {type: 'websocket',
                                 host: t, port: p}
                               ]});
    client.connect();
    client.transport.onopen=this.onopen;
    client.transport.onclose=this.onclose;
    client.onconnect = client.ondisconnect = this.getStatus;
    client.onnotify = this.recvNotify;
    let stream$ = new Observable(observer => {
    let interval = setInterval(() =>{
    observer.next(client.transport.state);
         /*observer.error(client.transport.onclose);
         observer.complete();*/
    },1000);
    return() =>{
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    }).share();
    return stream$;
} catch (error) {
    console.log("catch.."+error);
    }
}

recvNotify(m) {
var method = m.name;
var value = m.data;
var buttonType = "EFT_PAN";
this.database.setMetadataKey(value,buttonType).then((result) => {
            console.log("Successfully saved the setMetadataKey.")
        }, (error) => {
            alert("ERROR: "+ error);
        });
}
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this please

Comment: it means javascript does not get value of `this.database`. Have you injected `database` service in component (file with recvNotify function ) eg: `private database: Database` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the first thing I do, and I can able to call from constructor method. Receive notify is not a component it’s a global service and database is a provider

Comment: Hi @Dhyey Is it possible to call a database provider method from global service?

Comment: How/Where do you call the `recvNotify()` method? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: @echonax Hi Thanks for your quick consideration, this is to communicate with a device over websocket. from the same service only i am calling this method

Comment: @NMNB yes but I suspect that you are calling the method in a callback so your `this` is not refering to your component

Comment: @echonax Hi I have updated my question. can you help me

Comment: @NMNB try `client.onnotify = this.recvNotify.bind(this);`

Comment: @echonax Hi i tried it, i am getting the same error. any other solution

Comment: @NMNB change `database: Database` to `private database: Database` inside the constructor

Comment: @NMNB any news?

Comment: No still trying to get this working, thank you for your support